# Discord.js MongoDB adding new object problem

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

I have Collection named **Account**
This is this collection:

---

```
userID: "1111111111111111111"
player: {
 something:{
  something2: {
   smth: 99
  },
  something3: {
   smth: 88
  }
 }
}
```

---

I want to add `something4 {smth: 77}`" into `something` from other collection or json file.
I tried with `Collection.findOneAndUpdate` or `Collection.insertOne` but nothing working.

Comment: add the code that you've tried !

Comment: First what i used was this: https://sourceb.in/22bb661574
next just tried with .insertOne but in insertOne can't find userID so just tried with .findOneAndUpdate but nothing changed after use command.

Comment: Did you test your query on DB ? tried to print inputs and responses from `.findOne()` calls ?

Comment: When i tried with this code what i sended then object "something" changed into string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going the right direction with `collection.findOneAndUpdate()`
you need to do:

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate({usrID:"1111111111111111111"}, [{
    $set:{something4:{smth: 77}}
}]);
```

See the update operators page https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/